# How to create a new column showing when a change to an observation occurred?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data-frame formatted like so:

| Contract | Agreement_Date | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2017-02-10 | 2020-02-03 |
| A | 2017-02-10 | 2020-02-04 |
| A | 2017-02-11 | **2020-02-09** |
| A | 2017-02-11 | 2020-02-10 |
| A | 2017-02-11 | 2020-04-21 |
| B | 2017-02-14 | 2020-08-01 |
| B | 2017-02-15 | **2020-08-11** |
| B | 2017-02-17 | **2020-10-14** |
| C | 2017-02-11 | 2020-12-12 |
| C | 2017-02-11 | 2020-12-16 |

In this data-frame I have multiple observations for each contract. For some of the contracts, their Agreement_Date changes as new amendments occur. As an example, Contract A had its agreements change from 2017-02-10 to 2017-02-11, and Contract B had its agreement_date change 3 times. Contract C had no change to  Agreement_Date

What I would like is an output that looks like so:

| Contract | Date | Number_of_Changes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2020-02-09 | 1 |
| B | 2017-08-11 | 2 |
| B | 2017-10-14 | 2 |

Where the Date column shows when the change to Agreement_Date occurs (e.g. for contract A the Agreement_Date first went from 2017-02-10 to 2017-02-11 on 2020-02-09). This is shown in bold in my first table. I then want a Number_of_Changes column which simply shows how many times the Agreement_Date changed for that contract.

I have been working on this for a few hours to no avail, so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

I posted a previous answer, but realised it's not what you expected. Would this one work out though ?

```
#Create 'progressive' number of changes column per Contract
df['Changes']=df.groupby('Contract')['Agreement_Date'].transform(lambda x:(x!=x.shift()).cumsum())-1


#Assign to new df, filter for changes and drop duplicates assuming it's already sorted per 'Date'
newdf=df[df['Changes']>0].drop_duplicates(subset=['Contract','Changes'])[['Contract','Date','Changes']]

#Reassign values of 'changes' for max 'Change' per Contract
newdf['Changes']=newdf.groupby('Contract')['Changes'].transform('max')

newdf
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem revolves around setting up some pieces for later computational use. You'll need multiple passes to

1. shift the dates & retrieve the records where the changes occur
2. calculate the number of changes that occurred

We can do this by working with the groupby object in 2 steps.

```
contract_grouped = df.groupby('Contract')['Agreement_Date']

# subset data based on whether or not a date change occurred
shifted_dates = contract_grouped.shift()
changed_df = df.loc[
    shifted_dates.ne(df['Agreement_Date']) & shifted_dates.notnull()
].copy()

# calculate counts and assign back to df
changed_df['count'] = changed_df['Contract'].map(contract_grouped.nunique() - 1)
del changed_df['Date'] # unneeded column

print(changed_df)
  Contract Agreement_Date  count
2        A     2017-02-11      1
6        B     2017-02-15      2
7        B     2017-02-17      2
```

Here is the same approach written out with method chaining & assignment expression syntax. If the above is more readable to you, please use that. I put this here mainly because I enjoy writing my `pandas` answers both ways.

```py
changed_df = (
    df.groupby('Contract')['Agreement_Date']
    .pipe(lambda grouper: 
        df.loc[
            (shifted := grouper.shift()).ne(df['Agreement_Date'])
             & shifted.notnull()
        ]
    .assign(count=lambda d: d['Contract'].map(grouper.nunique().sub(1)))
    .drop(columns='Date')
    )
)

print(changed_df)
  Contract Agreement_Date  count
2        A     2017-02-11      1
6        B     2017-02-15      2
7        B     2017-02-17      2
```

Answer (score 0):

This gives the desired output: first, generate the difference between one row and the one before and locate the index of the rows when the value is neither 0 nor NaT; then create a 'change' column based on the count

```
df.Agreement_Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Agreement_Date)

out = df.loc[np.where((df.groupby('Contract')['Agreement_Date'].diff().notna())&(df['Agreement_Date'].diff()!='0 days'))][['Contract', 'Date']]
out['Change'] = out.groupby('Contract').transform('count').values
out.set_index('Contract',drop=True, inplace=True)

Output:
                Date  Change
Contract                    
A         2020-02-09       1
B         2020-08-11       2
B         2020-10-14       2
```